# How and where does Windows save the password for pgp keys?

Tags: passwords, windows, enigmail

When I use Eingmail in Thunderbird on Windows I can choose to save the pgp key password. Where is this password stored? Is it safely stored? How does that work compared to a Ubuntu System?

Comment: This is very old, but maybe still applicable [Enigmail List Question - 2003](https://www.enigmail.net/list_archive/2003-04/msg00161.html) ... someone else probably has more recent information.